# Receiving monthly subscription amount on website instead on iOS app ( without using IAP )

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

Currently I am working on implementing a universal iOS app, which features **basic and premium subscriptions**. A user can signup and subscribe using website console. Some of the features in iOS app are applicable to premium subscribed user. In case of basic subscribed user tries to access those features we showing an alert saying "Please subscribe to premium subscription". Other than this no where we are providing external links in the app. This iOS app will be a paid application.

```
I have few querys related to this iOS app.
```

1. Does Apple allow to collect the subscription amount out side the iOS app ( without using IAP ) like I mentioned above?
2. In future if we include signup functionality in iOS app and collecting subscription amount using external payment gateways ( without using IAP ). Does Apple allow to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Apple will reject all apps that use third party payment methods. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566671/ios-app-does-apple-allow-3rd-party-payments-inside-app